# SQL SUM different value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT u.*, c1.FAME AS Fame1, c2.FAME AS Fame2, c3.FAME AS Fame3, c4.FAME AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_1 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, c1.FAME AS Fame1, c2.FAME AS Fame2, c3.FAME AS Fame3, c4.FAME AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_2 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, c1.FAME AS Fame1, c2.FAME AS Fame2, c3.FAME AS Fame3, c4.FAME AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_3 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, c1.FAME AS Fame1, c2.FAME AS Fame2, c3.FAME AS Fame3, c4.FAME AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_4 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)  
) AS a
WHERE UID IN (378358,378359)
```

The result:

```
UID         Char1       Char2       Char3       Fame1       Fame2       Fame3       Fame4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
378358      46497       130         40365       NULL        10          8839        NULL
378358      46497       130         40365       NULL        2470        8839        NULL
378359      36935       121         123         NULL        17285       NULL        292
378359      36935       121         123         NULL        17285       NULL        1277
```

As you can see the result above all data are same except the columns **Fame4** for `UID=378359` and **Fame2** for `UID=378358`.

The question is how can I **SUM** the **different values** (only in Fame columns) ONLY and return as 1 row for each `UID`.

the desired result:

```
UID         Char1       Char2       Char3       Fame1       Fame2       Fame3       Fame4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
378358      46497       130         40365       NULL        2480        8839        NULL
378359      36935       121         123         NULL        17285       NULL        1569
```

Comment: GROUP BY UID, MAX on char columns and SUM on fame columns.

Comment: @Mihai can you provide me a full query for that?

Comment: @KingsleyChew Just use `SUM(DISTINCT columnname)` with `GROUP BY`. See my answer for details.

Comment: By the way, you should probably use only **one** UserInfo table with a column  to designate: 1, 2, 3, 4. Else, you will need such long queries like this.

Comment: @Parfait it's the default database schema for an old game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to `SUM` only different values use `SUM(DISTINCT columnname)`:

```
SELECT  UID,
        Char1,
        Char2,
        Char3,
        SUM(DISTINCT Fame1) Fame1,
        SUM(DISTINCT Fame2) Fame2,
        SUM(DISTINCT Fame3) Fame3,
        SUM(DISTINCT Fame4) Fame4
FROM (
--Here comes your sub-query
) AS a
WHERE UID IN (378358,378359)
GROUP BY UID, Char1, Char2, Char3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Group By**:

```
SELECT 
   a.UID,a.Char1,a.Char2,a.Char3,
   SUM(a.Fame1),
   SUM(a.Fame2),
   SUM(a.Fame3),
   SUM(a.Fame4) 
FROM (
    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_1 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_2 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_3 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_4 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)  
) AS a
WHERE UID IN (378358,378359)
GROUP By a.UID,a.Char1,a.Char2,a.Char3
```

Comment: Yes it return as 1 row now for each UID but i only want the SUM for DIFFERENT value only in Fame columns

Comment: i think it give you SUM for DIFFERENT value only in Fame columns

Comment: What i want to sum is Fame2 10 + 2470 and Fame4 292 + 1277. The others fame stay the same. But your query SUM all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   a.UID,a.Char1,a.Char2,a.Char3,
   a.Fame1,
   SUM(a.Fame2) AS Fame2,
   a.Fame3,
   SUM(a.Fame4) AS Fame4
FROM (
    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_1 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_2 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_3 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) UNION 

    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(c1.FAME,0) AS Fame1, ISNULL(c2.FAME,0) AS Fame2, ISNULL(c3.FAME,0) AS Fame3, ISNULL(c4.FAME,0) AS Fame4 
        FROM UserInfo_4 AS u 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_1 AS c1 ON c1.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3) 
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_2 AS c2 ON c2.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_3 AS c3 ON c3.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)
            LEFT JOIN CharInfo_4 AS c4 ON c4.UID IN (u.Char1, u.Char2, u.Char3)  
) AS a
WHERE UID IN (378358,378359)
GROUP By a.UID,a.Char1,a.Char2,a.Char3,a.Fame1,a.Fame3
```